# Mouse behaves weirdly with Caps Lock remapped to Control on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, windows-registry

I have remapped Caps Lock to Control by using the following registry script on Windows 7:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout]
"Scancode Map"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,02,00,00,00,1d,00,3a,00,00,00,00,00
```

Everything works as expected on keyboard (for example, Caps Lock + a selects everything, Caps Lock + t opens a new tab on web browsers, etc.). However, I cannot use the mouse with Caps Lock.

While I hold down the Caps Lock, mouse does not move. Also Caps Lock + Left Click does not open a link in the new tab. It doesn't open a link at all.

How to fix this?

## Edit:

The issue stopped when I used a separate mouse and a separate keyboard, instead of using the touchpad and the keyboard of the laptop.